# Real-time websocket connection. Delay receiving websocket messages with tornado

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, deep-learning, tornado

This is my first question so, I'm sorry if I need important information.

I'm developing a bot for a browser game. It is possible to host the game in my browser using an API, and I can access information such as the game state at each tick (60 ticks per second)

My idea was to create a connection between a WebSocket in the game source code (which is in **javascript**) and a local server in **python** using **tornado** that receives the game state ate each tick and responds with a simulate keypress using **win32api**.

Javascript WebSocket:

```js
socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9999');
socket.onopen = () => socket.send('hello');

onGameTick()
{
    socket.send(gamestate);
}
```

Python server:

```py
class WSHandler(WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print('new connection')
      
    def on_message(self, message):
        print(message)
        checkGameStateandPlay()
            
    def on_close(self):
        print('connection closed')
 
    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True

class MyApplication(web.Application):
    is_closing = False

    def signal_handler(self, signum, frame):
        logging.info('exiting...')
        self.is_closing = True

    def try_exit(self):
        if self.is_closing:
            # clean up here
            ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()
            logging.info('exit success')

application = MyApplication([
    (r'/', WSHandler),
])
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    options.parse_command_line()
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, application.signal_handler)
    http_server = httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(9999)
    myIP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    print('*** Websocket Server Started at %s***' % myIP)
    ioloop.PeriodicCallback(application.try_exit, 100).start()
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Now MY PROBLEM IS:

There is a huge delay on the messages received by the server. Whenever I try to put the bot reacting to the game state and playing, it takes a delay of like 2 seconds to react.

I tried a program as simples as sending a string from the javascript program to the python server on every tick (60 per second) and I also tried other rates like 2 ticks per second, and I printed the received message on the *on_message* function, and it never prints with the correct rate.
If I try sending with the rate of 2 ticks/s, the server-side will print the messages at an inconstant rate. Usually prints 2 messages at the end of each second instead of printing each message and the end of half a second.

For a real time bot, this needs to work on at least 30 ticks/s, and I don't know what is wrong.